# Python: Append a parsed string but throw out non-compliant values?

Tags: python, parsing, exception

Warning: I'm a total newbie; apologies if I didn't search for the right thing before submitting this question. I found lots on how to ignore errors, but nothing quite like what I'm trying to do here.

I have a simple script that I'm using to grab data off a database, parse some fields apart, and re-write the parsed values back to the database. Multiple users are submitting to the database according to a delimited template, but there is some degree of non-compliance, meaning sometimes the string won't contain all/any delimiters. My script needs to be able to handle those instances by throwing them out entirely.

I'm having trouble throwing out non-compliant strings, rather than just ignoring the errors they raise. When I've tried try-except-pass, I've ended up getting errors when my script attempts to append parsed values into the array I'm ultimately writing back to the db.

Originally, my script said:

```
def parse_comments(comments):
    parts = comments.split("||")
    if len(parts) < 20:
        raise ValueError("Comment didn't have enough || delimiters")
return Result._make([parts[i].strip() for i in xrange(2, 21, 3)])
```

Fully compliant uploads would append Result to an array and write back to db.

I've tried try/except:

```
def parse_comments(comments):
    parts = comments.split("||")
    try:
        Thing._make([parts[i].strip() for i in xrange(2, 21, 3)])
    except:
        pass
    return Thing
```

But I end up getting an error when I try and append the parsed values to an array -- specifically TypeError: 'type' object has no attribute '**getitem**'

I've also tried:

```
def parse_comments(comments):
    parts = comments.split("||")
    if len(parts) >= 20:
        Thing._make([parts[i].strip() for i in xrange(2, 21, 3)])
    else:
        pass
    return Thing
```

but to no avail.

tl;dr: I need to parse stuff and append parsed items. If a string can't be parsed how I want it, I want my code to ignore that string entirely and move on.

Comment: first, len(parts) should be >= 21 if you want to call parts[20] (which you do in your list comprehension).

Comment: second, are you sure `comments` are what you think they are? maybe the error is not raised because your comments are actually compliant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But I end up getting an error when I try and append the parsed values to an array -- specifically TypeError: 'type' object has no attribute 'getitem'

Because `Thing` means *the Thing class itself*, not *an instance of* that class.

You need to think more clearly about what you want to return when the data is invalid. It may be the case that you can't return anything directly usable here, so that the calling code has to explicitly check.

Comment: Thanks @Karl, I ended up going back to the drawing board here and ultimately getting something slightly different to work.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand everything you want to do. But I think you are not catching the error at the right place. You said yourself that it arose when you wanted to append the value to an array. So maybe you should do:

```
try:
   # append the parsed values to an array 
except TypeError:
   pass
```

You should give the exception type to catch after `except`, otherwise it will catch [any exception](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HandlingExceptions), even a user's `CTRL+C` which raise a [KeyboardInterrupt](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.KeyboardInterrupt).